# getting 502 Bad Gateway on eks aws-alb-ingress

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I created in AWS a EKS Cluster via Terraform using terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws as module. This cluster has one pod (golang app) using nodeport as service and ingress. The problem I have is that I'm getting 502 bad gateway when I hit the endpoint.

My config:

**Deployment:**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: golang-deployment
  labels:
    app: golang-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: golang-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: golang-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: golang-app
        image: 019496914213.dkr.ecr.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/goland:1.0
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
```

**service:**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: golang-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: golang-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
```

**Ingress:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  labels:
    app: app
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/v2
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: golang-service
                port:
                  number: 9000



kubectl get service
golang-service    NodePort    172.20.44.34     <none>        9000:32184/TCP   106m
```

The security groups for the cluster and nodes were created by terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws module.

I checked severals things:

```
kubectl port-forward golang-deployment-5894d8d6fc-ktmmb 9000:9000
```

**WORKS!** I can see the golang app using localhost:9000 in my computer

```
kubectl exec curl -i --tty nslookup golang-app

Server:    172.20.0.10
Address 1: 172.20.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      golang-app
Address 1: 172.20.130.130 golang-app.default.svc.cluster.local
```

**WORKS!**

```
kubectl exec curl -i --tty curl golang-app:9000

curl: (7) Failed to connect to golang-app port 9000: Connection refused
```

**NOT WORKS**

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling the **service** not deployment.

**golang-service** is svc name instead of deployment name

```
kubectl exec curl -i --tty curl golang-service:9000
```

Comment: I tried it and didn't work.  I got the same: curl: (7) Failed to connect to golang-service port 9000: Connection refused

Comment: you trying to curl internally right ? or using alb outside ? over the internet using alb endpoint?

Comment: I'm executing curl from my computer. I have kubectl config to point to aws cluster.

Comment: got it, so it's like you are doing exec inside curl container and from there trying to access the service right ?

Comment: Yes, curl is a pod so I'm trying to access from one pod(curl) to other(golang-app) using: curl golang-service:9000

Comment: you can use the service always that's best practice. To debug more use IP of POD and hit curl to check what's output. make sure both pods are in same namespace.

Comment: kubectl exec curl -i --tty curl 10.0.2.177:9000: WORKS! So the problem is the service nodeport, right? Why?

Comment: that's weird service and port should work.

Comment: did you ever get this figured out precisely?